# get function does not fetch data from dynamically created fields in form

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I am trying to store data from dynamically created fields using PHP. The fixed fields are not a problem. I am having troubles in GET-ing the "flex" fields; that is, the fields a user can generate (till the max of 3) to add more participants for an event. I have searched this site, the internet in general and studied the PHP manual. It seems as if the solutions lies in working with `foreach`, but I am not smart and skilled enough (yet) to compose the right function.

The code I came up with so far (work in progress) is:

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC etc >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      var counter = 0;
      var limit = 3;
      var veldwaarde ="";

      function addInput(divName) {
        if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("More then " + counter +  " partcipants not possible ");
        } else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "<table><tr><td>Naam deelnemer " + (counter + 1) + "</td><td><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'/></td></tr>" + "<tr><td>Schoenmaat deelnemer " + (counter + 1) + "</td><td><br><input type='text' name='myInputs2[]'></td></tr></table>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <form name="formulier" method="get" action="invoer_data.php" >
    <table>
      <tr><td width="15%">Naam:</td><td width="15%"><input type="text" name="naam"   >id="naam" value="" ></td></tr>
      <tr><td width="15%">Schoenmaat:</td><td><input type="text" name="schoenmaat" >    >id="schoenmaat" value="" ></td></tr>
      <!--  <tr><td width="15%">Adres:</td><td><input type="text" name="adres" id="adres"   >value="" ></td></tr>
            <tr><td width="15%">Postcode:</td><td><input type="text" name="postcode" >id="postcode" value="" ></td></tr>
      <tr><td width="15%">Woonplaats:</td><td><input type="text" name="woonplaats" >id="woonplaats" value="" ></td></tr>
      <tr><td width="15%">E-mail:</td><td><input type="text" name="email" id="email" >value="" ></td></tr>
      <tr><td width="15%">Telefoon overdag:</td><td><input type="text" name="telefoon" >id="telefoon" value=""></td></tr> -->
      <tr><td  width="15%">More partcipants:</td><td><div id="dynamicInput" > <a href="" >onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');return false;"><p style="color:red;">Add (max 3) >partcipants</p></a></td></tr>

      <td><input type="submit" name="verzenden"  value="Verzenden"></td>
    </table>
  </form>
```

PHP:

```php
<?php
// collect varaiables
@$naam = addslashes($_GET['naam']);
@$schoenmaat = addslashes($_GET['schoenmaat']);
@$adres = addslashes($_GET['adres']);
@$postcode = addslashes($_GET['postcode']);
@$woonplaats = addslashes($_GET['woonplaats']);
@$email = addslashes($_GET['email']);
@$telefoon = addslashes($_GET['telefoon']);
// next two lines are for the dynamically generated fields
@$myInputs = addslashes($_GET['myInputs']);
@$myInputs2 = addslashes($_GET['myInputs2']);

// Validation
if (strlen($naam) == 0) {
  die("<p align=\"center\"><font face=\"Vrinda\" size=\"4\"color=\"#FF0000\">First field is empty</font></p>");
}

//saving record in a text file to test the GET function
$pfw_file_name = "invoerDynvelden.txt";
$pfw_first_raw = "naam,schoenmaat,adres,postcode,woonplaats,email,telefoon,naam2,schoenmaat2,naam3,schoenmaat3,naam4,schoenmaat4\r\n";
$pfw_values = "$naam,$schoenmaat,$adres,$postcode,$woonplaats,$email,$telefoon,$naam2,$schoenmaat2,$naam3,$schoenmaat3,$naam4,$schoenmaat4\r\n";
$pfw_is_first_row = false;
if(!file_exists($pfw_file_name)) {
  $pfw_is_first_row = true;
}
if (!$pfw_handle = fopen($pfw_file_name, 'a+')) {
  die("Cannot open file ($pfw_file_name)");
  exit;
}
if ($pfw_is_first_row)
{
  if (fwrite($pfw_handle, $pfw_first_raw ) === FALSE) {
    die("Cannot write to file ($pfw_filename)");
    exit;
  }
}
if (fwrite($pfw_handle, $pfw_values) === FALSE) {
  die("Cannot write to file ($pfw_filename)");
  exit;
}
fclose($pfw_handle);
//saving record to MySQL database DBxxxxx still to be developed
?>
<body>
<a href="index.htm">Returm to entry screen</a><br/>
</body>
```

Comment: Do you think this text is readable?

Comment: Dear Sir,I appereciate your feedback and need some tips to improve the readabilty, since I followed the forums guidelines to publish the code. Later on I added the link <dynveld.howardwoei.nl> but I als read that it has te be reviewed before publishing.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting your dynamic inputs like this in the html / javascript:

```
 name='myInputs[]'
               ^^ an array
```

So to get your values in php, you would need to loop through:

```
 $_GET['myInputs']    // this is an array
```

using for example a `foreach`.

If you just want to visualise the values, you could also use something like:

```
implode(', ', $_GET['myInputs'])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeroen; Ik managed to aplly the for each and it works fine. The next problem I ran into is how to store the data tha the foreach retrieved from the input array, tot the MYSQLdatabase. The fields for the extra data (participants) are there, but I am having a hard time to store in an appropiate format(just like the fixed fields). What I have found so far is :> $sqldata = array (serialize($session_data), $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']);> but I just cannot figure out how to implement this the right way. Tips are appreciated (you can use the form for your bizz overthere in Peru :-)

Comment: Oops Don't bother anymore: I finally managed to get it working with>    $extras=serialize($deelnemer2);
>    $klompmaat=serialize($schoenmaat2);next issue however is that only the last (of three) added fields (= the last element of the array)gets stored in the txt file.I will work on that and would appreciate a tip from anyone.Thnxs in advance